# Google InAppBilling returns null

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, in-app-billing

I am developing a hybrid mobile app by `Cordova 3`. For `InAppBiling` I have used this plugin https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling.

I have made a sample just like what is introduced in the site. But in my app when I call `inappbilling.init(successHandler, errorHandler, { showLog: true });` the errorHandler is called with `error: null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weired,

I found there is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in `line 266` in `IabHelper.java`.
I commented `Line 266` as below and every things has become right, can anyone describe this.

```
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND");
//        serviceIntent.setPackage("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht");
```